# Trim the grid in boundaries of a shapefile

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, esri-grid-format

I have extracted the London Shapefile  from https://data.gov.uk/dataset/6cdebf5d-c69b-4480-8c9c-53ab8a816b9d/statistical-gis-boundary-files-for-london and uploaded London_Borough_Excluding_MHW.shp in QGIS to draw a grid . I am able to draw a grid using the extent layer of the shapefile uploaded . I get the grid mapped to layer as below [image]

How can I go from the first visualisation to the below one , where the grid is fitted into the shapefile below and not lying on top of it

[image]

I tried clip but it changes nothing , Any pointers will be helpful as you can find i am a novice user of QGIS . The grid is 100 m * 100m in the 2nd visualisation so its finer than 1st Grid Visualisation

Comment: It looks like you need the Vector tool> Geoprocessing> Intersection ...

Comment: @Cyril Thanks it works , Intersection with the input layer as shape file and grid as the overlapping layer